# How to determine, from web part, if document's content type inherits from a specified base content type?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

SharePoint newbie here.

I have a web part that is attached to SharePoint's edit page [EditForm.aspx]. How do I determine if the document being edited is linked to a content type that inherits, at any level of its inheritance chain, from a specified base type?

For instance, I have a base content type called "Document Base". I want this web part to take action if and only if the document being edited ultimately derives from this base type. How can I determine this from within my web part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SPContentType wantedBase = web.ContentTypes["Document Base"];
    if (listItem.ContentType.Id.IsChildOf(wantedBase.Id))
       // Yes this is a child

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I see that `SPContext.Current` exposes the item being edited, and that knowledge combined with your answer are exactly what I needed.